# Query rows for which meta data key does not exist

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT wposts.ID AS ID
FROM `wp_posts` AS wposts
JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS postmeta ON (wposts.ID = postmeta.post_id)
WHERE wposts.post_type = 'post'
AND wposts.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts, `wp_postmeta` AS postmeta2
    WHERE wp_posts.ID = postmeta2.post_id
    AND postmeta2.meta_key = 'z_latitude'
)
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
```

The query is a mess. I simply want to query all rows that do not have a certain meta key.
Above, I query all rows that have the meta key and then exclude them from the outer query.
I don't know how to write this better.

Comment: Please stop abusing other people answers, you can add comments if you want but don't edit their answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use an *outer* join via a `left join` and grab rows that *didn't* join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wposts.ID AS ID
FROM `doxy_posts` AS wposts
left JOIN `doxy_postmeta` AS postmeta ON wposts.ID = postmeta.post_id
WHERE postmeta.post_id is null
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: you forgot to include the `postmeta.meta_key = 'z_latitude'` condition in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT wposts.ID AS ID
FROM doxy_posts AS wposts
  LEFT JOIN doxy_postmeta AS postmeta
    ON wposts.ID = postmeta.post_id
    AND postmeta.meta_key = 'z_latitude'
WHERE wposts.post_type = 'post' 
  AND postmeta.post_id IS NULL
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
```

or:

```
SELECT wposts.ID AS ID
FROM doxy_posts AS wposts
WHERE wposts.post_type = 'post' 
  AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT * 
          FROM doxy_postmeta AS postmeta
          WHERE wposts.ID = postmeta.post_id
            AND postmeta.meta_key = 'z_latitude'
        ) 
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
```