# SQL simple left join provides error

Tags: mysql, join

I'm using the answer provided here: [Query rows for which meta data key does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483228/query-rows-for-which-meta-data-key-does-not-exist)

```
   UPDATE table1
   SET table1.id = table2.id
   FROM table1
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
   WHERE table.id IS NULL
```

I'm looking to set all id's in table 1 to the corresponding id in table2 only where table1's id is null but this gives "mysql error".

Any thoughts?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most databases, MySQL has a [unique syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for a join in combination with an update:

```
UPDATE table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
SET table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't join in an UPDATE statement (edit - maybe you can).  You need a subselect that returns exactly one row.  Also your query makes no sense if id is the join column - I'll assume you're joining on something else.

I think something like this is correct (haven't tested it).

```
UPDATE table1 outer
SET id = (
    SELECT table2.id 
    FROM table2 JOIN table1 USING(join_column) -- or ON if the columns aren't the same
    WHERE join_column = outer.join_column
)
WHERE id is null
```

Comment: Yeah you can, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e422/1/0).  Aliasing like you propose is almost never allowed though (`update table1 outer`)